# Referenced variables in text powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I would like to insert a variable in a textbox in PowerPoint by use of an Excel macro. The variable must refer to a Excel cell and be updated whenever the excel cell value changes.

I have already tried OLE objects, linking and embedding.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the textbox already present in the powerpoint, or would you like a new one to be added?

Comment: I think the only method to do this would be to add a call to the worksheet_change method that will open the powerpoint and update the shape properties.  Admittedly, writing this code will be a pretty significant challenge, but if you name your objects cleverly enough it should be doable (ie name the textbox after the cell location so you can access the desired textbox easily and efficiently)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace the entire contents of the text box with the contents of the Excel cell?  If so, you can use the name of the text box shape to point to the cell ( ie, name the shape "C1R4" or the like).  Or add a tag or tags to the shape to accomplish the same thing:

```
With oSh
   .Tags.Add "Row", "42"
   .Tags.Add "Col", "5"
End With
```

It gets trickier if you want to replace just some portion of the text within the shape:

2017 projected sales: [value from Excel goes here]

You can still do something like:

2017 projected sales: @@R42C5@@

where @@ delineates a "placeholder" bit of text that you'll replace with a value from Excel.

But that's a one-shot deal ... once you've replaced the text, you can't come back later and re-do the replacement.  You may not NEED to.  But if so, you can again resort to tags.  Tag the shape with a tag whose value is "2017 projected sales: @@R42C5@@" then use the tag value to replace all the text in the shape and then do the substitution with the text from Excel.